# Можно ли при срабатывании события на одном элементе вызывать событие на другом? JS

Tags: javascript

```js
const target = document.getElementById('target');
target.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('target click')
});

const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
wrapper.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('Что-нибудь, что вызовет событие клика на кнопке'));
```

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #ccc
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
  <button id="target">target</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спустя несколько месяцев, я наконец нашел как это делается правильно. Можно вызвать любое событие.

Вот несколько ссылок:

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent

https://learn.javascript.ru/dispatch-events

```js
const target = document.getElementById('target');
target.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('target click')
});

const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
wrapper.addEventListener('click', () => target.dispatchEvent(new Event('click')));
```

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #ccc
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
  <button id="target">target</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const target = document.getElementById('target');
target.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('target click')
});

const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
wrapper.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('Что-нибудь, что вызовет событие клика на кнопке');
  target.click();
 });
```

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #ccc
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
  <button id="target">target</button>
</div>
```

Так?